# how to assign an array to a pointer inside a structure without causing memory leakage

Tags: c++

I am reading data from a file in a function and saving the data to a temporary array. Then I am passing the array to a pointer inside a structure. But when I check the output in the main function, the data that I am reading is compromised and there is memory leakage for some values. 
I want to know how I can read the data in the main function without causing memory leakage.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

struct myWeather
{
    wchar_t *cityName;
    float *temperature, *pressure, *direction, *wind;
    myWeather *next, *prev;
};

myWeather *readData();

int main()
{
    myWeather *location, *currLoc;

    location = readData();
    currLoc = location;

    for(int c=0; c<49; c++)
   {
        cout<< "temp value"<< c+1<<": "<< (*currLoc->temperature+c)<<endl;
   }

    for(int f=0; f<1441; f++)
    {
    cout<< "pressure value"<< f+1<<": "<< *(currLoc->pressure+f)<<endl;
    }

    for(int g=0; g<720; g++)
    {
        cout<< "Dir value"<< g+1<<": "<< *(currLoc->direction+g)<<endl;
    }

    for(int h=0; h<720; h++)
    {
        cout<< "Wind value"<< h+1<<": "<< *(currLoc->wind+h)<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

myWeather *readData()
{
    myWeather *headPTR;
    char cityText[80];
    wchar_t cityNym[80];
    string myCity;
    float tmpData[49], prsData[1441], winData[720], dirData[720];
    int len;

    ifstream weatherFile ("Data.txt", ios::in);

    headPTR = new myWeather;
    getline(weatherFile, myCity);
    len= myCity.length();
    myCity.copy(cityText, len, 0);
    cityText[len]='\0';
    mbstowcs(cityNym, cityText, strlen(cityText)+1);
    headPTR->cityName = new wchar_t;
    headPTR->cityName= cityNym;
    weatherFile>> cityText;
    weatherFile>>len;

    for(int a=0; a<49; a++)
    {
        weatherFile>>tmpData[a];
    }
    headPTR->temperature = new float;
    headPTR->temperature = tmpData;

    weatherFile>> cityText;
    weatherFile>>len;
    for(int b=0; b<1441;b++)
    {
        weatherFile>>prsData[b];
    }

    headPTR->pressure= new float;
    headPTR->pressure= prsData;

    weatherFile>> cityText;
    weatherFile>>len;
    for(int d=0; d<720; d++)
    {
        weatherFile>>dirData[d];
    }
    headPTR->wind= new float;
    headPTR->wind= dirData;

    weatherFile>> cityText;
    weatherFile>>len;
    for(int e=0; e<720; e++)
    {
        weatherFile>>winData[e];
    }
    headPTR->direction = new float;
    headPTR->direction = winData;

    weatherFile.close();

    return headPTR;
}
```

Comment: It's simple - don't use `new`. And using it for built-in types is just ridiculous. Well, you reassign the pointer afterwards to the beginning of each of those arrays, and you end up with invalid pointers after the function returns...

Comment: Learn about unique and shared ptr. Don't do explicit memory management in modern C++.

Comment: @LogicStuff I did comment out the 'new' but I still get the same values. The temperature value are okay and the direction values. The problem is with the wind values from 167-370 and pressure values from 1115-1441.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I understand that you are trying to give him good advice, but in school they often tell you the way that they want things to happen, which are not often the way that they should be.......

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your case instead using an array you should use old `std::vector<float>` and `wstring` (for `cityName`). This is exactly what you need.

In case of `next` and `previous` you can use `std::unique_ptr` for `next` and raw pointer for `previous`.

Basically it may look like this:

```
struct myWeather
{
    std::wstring cityName;
    std::vector<float> temperature, pressure, direction, wind;
    std::unique_ptr<myWeather> next;
    myWeather prev;
};
```

But on other hand it looks like you are implementing double linking list which is already provided, so IMO this aproach is better:

```
struct myWeather
{
    std::wstring cityName;
    std::vector<float> temperature, pressure, direction, wind;
};

using WeatherRecords = std::list<myWeather>;
```

So in fact you do not need any fancy pointers or use `new` `delete` operators.

Comment: In this case I have not learnt vectors and I am told to explicitly use arrays. the reason for me using wchar_t is because this is just a sample, i didn't want to post the whole program because it will be asking you to do my work. I am using the program in win32 API.